# Clarification regarding ActiveX cab Version

Tags: asp.net, activex, cab

I'm building CAB for ActiveX contol and I need the following clarification:

I've control.ocx which have 2.0.0.1 version.

When I'm embedding my control I'm putting the following tag:

Tommorow, I'm adding new functionality to my ocx and versing it as 3.0.0.1

How my  tag should look like?

Should it content codebase="control.cab#Version=3,0,0,1" attribute? 
Is it correct?
Can I set version for cab file?
How can I tell my client to update my ActiveX component?

Best regards,
Danny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and don't forget to change the version=w.x.y.z attribute in the .inf file inside your cab.